# ANT script to read a value from a file

Tags: search, ant, build

I am having following input file, I need an ant script command to get the Test value when its having value (1 of 1) in the line:

(123) "Test 1" (0 of 1)

(456) "Test 2" (1 of 1)

(789) "Test 3" (0 of 1)

Expected output:
Test 2

I tried using regexp, but its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ant is not a scripting language. It's designed to process collections of files, so is poorly optimized for performing analysis on individual files.

I would suggest you use an external program to scan the file, for example:

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <target name="build">
    <exec executable="awk">
      <arg line="'/\(1 of 1\)/ {print $2,$3}' input.txt"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

</project>
```

Or embed a scripting language like Javascript or Groovy within your ANT build.